# Blackberry not connecting to local IP on network using WIFI

Tags: web-services, cordova, networking, jquery-mobile, blackberry

I'm building a mobile application using Phonegap and jQuery mobile on Zend Studio, and I'm doing this on a macbook pro running OSX Mountain Lion.

I have deployed the application to an iPhone 4, Samsung Galaxy Android Device, and a Blackberry Curve.

The application calls a webservice for various functions. This webservice is currently situated on another macbook on our local wifi network. The iPhone and Android connects to the webservice and works 100% when connected to the wifi network.

However, the Blackberry, when performing the webservice call, get's a SQUID ERROR?? which tells us that the url cannot be found. We're using the local IP of the macbook running the server to connect. In the browser of the Blackberry, when I enter the IP Addresss alone, I reach the IIS running on the webserver. But when I make the webservice call from the application itself, I get the URL NOT FOUND error.

I have also turned off the Blackberry cellular network and made sure it was only connected to the local WIFI connection, but this does not solve the problem.

Has anyone else encountered this type of issue before?

Thanks.

Comment: will you ensure that the url is accessable?. I mean call the url directly from the browser.

Comment: Even directly from the browser, it does not connect. But Ios and Android do connect without an issue, so it's definately a BB thing.

Comment: if its not connectiong via directly , thats not the coding problem. its either related with device or ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to your Url this:

```
url += ";interface=wifi";
```

You can look on this reference:
[blackberry](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Open_a_WiFi_HTTP_connection_509041_11.jsp)

Comment: OOOH! Thank you! I'll test shortly!